# android aidl, cannot bind to service?

Tags: android, aidl

Are there anyone knows why?

Activity

```
    private IExternalDeviceScannerService myService = null;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myService = IExternalDeviceScannerService.Stub.asInterface(arg1);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
    ......
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExternalDeviceScannerService.class);
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    ....
```

Service

```
class ScannerServiceAIDL extends IExternalDeviceScannerService.Stub {
.......
}
    @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ScannerServiceAIDL();
}
```

My activity is never connected to the service, even I waited few seconds!

Comment: Have you declared the service in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Check the return value of bindService(..), it will return `true` if you've correctly defined the service & if a service connection will be made.

Comment: Yes, I've declared it in the service;

Comment: And the value of bindService is always false! why?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and executed the code without any problem. I think you made any mistake anywhere in your project. My successfully executed code is below.

### IExternalDeviceScannerService.aidl

```
package com.example.aidltest;

interface IExternalDeviceScannerService
{
    int getIntValue();
}
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".ExternalDeviceScannerService"></service>
</application>
```

### Activity

```
private IExternalDeviceScannerService myService = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExternalDeviceScannerService.class);
    // Bind service here
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mConnection);
    myService = null;
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        myService = IExternalDeviceScannerService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        if (myService != null){
            try {
                Log.i("Value from AIDL", myService.getIntValue() +  "");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }            
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        myService = null;
    }
};
```

### Service

```
public class ExternalDeviceScannerService extends Service {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Service";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Stopped.");
    }

    final class ScannerServiceAIDL extends IExternalDeviceScannerService.Stub {
        public int getIntValue() throws RemoteException {
            return 20;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Service Bound.");
        return new ScannerServiceAIDL();
    }   
}
```

Have fun with AIDL!!! Thanks